# Pivoting dataframe ideas: from long to wide

Tags: python, r, pandas, pivot-table, reshape

I have a dataframe data records are **stacked** in a way where the **same subject have different measurements every 3 months or so**. For example, Subj BAR02002 has 4 different data records:

```
    Subj  months   X    Y    Z
BAR02002   0       14  53   52
BAR02002   3       24  61   96
BAR02002   6       5   53   3
BAR02002   9       3   64   33
BAR02003   0       22  63   55
BAR02003   6       44  22   53 
BAR02003   9       42  12   72
BAR02003   12      15  1    12
```

**I am trying to make BAR02002 makes up only one row instead of 4**. I believe this process is called reshaping data from long to wide (I could be wrong). To illustrate the final result:

```
Subj       X    Y    Z    X1    Y2    Z3   X2   Y3   Z3  ... 
BAR02002   14   53   52   24    61    96   5    53    3  ...    
BAR02003   0    22   63   55    NA    NA   NA   44   22  ...
```

The following code does not give what I want. Is there any way of transforming the data using pandas/python (or even R)?

```
df.pivot(index='Subj_FU', columns='Subj', values= ['Months','PM_N', ...])
```

Comment: pls provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @AnuragDabas I have edited the content, hope it makes more sense. I have provided with the minimal reproducible example

Comment: you provided your expected output as text.....which doesn't make any sense...post your initial dataframe as text so that anyone can reproduce the dataframe and do testing on it.

Comment: @AnuragDabas Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow I have updated the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` for new column and use it for parameter `columns`, last flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
df['g'] = df['months'].map({0:0, 3:1, 6:2, 9:3, 12:4})
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Subj', columns='g', values= ['X','Y','Z'], aggfunc='sum')
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
print (df1)
            X0    X1    X2    X3    X4    Y0    Y1    Y2    Y3   Y4    Z0  \
Subj                                                                        
BAR02002  14.0  24.0   5.0   3.0   NaN  53.0  61.0  53.0  64.0  NaN  52.0   
BAR02003  22.0   NaN  44.0  42.0  15.0  63.0   NaN  22.0  12.0  1.0  55.0   

            Z1    Z2    Z3    Z4  
Subj                              
BAR02002  96.0   3.0  33.0   NaN  
BAR02003   NaN  53.0  72.0  12.0
```

If use column `month`:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Subj', columns='months', values= ['X','Y','Z'], aggfunc='sum')
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
print (df1)
            X0    X3    X6    X9   X12    Y0    Y3    Y6    Y9  Y12    Z0  \
Subj                                                                        
BAR02002  14.0  24.0   5.0   3.0   NaN  53.0  61.0  53.0  64.0  NaN  52.0   
BAR02003  22.0   NaN  44.0  42.0  15.0  63.0   NaN  22.0  12.0  1.0  55.0   

            Z3    Z6    Z9   Z12  
Subj                              
BAR02002  96.0   3.0  33.0   NaN  
BAR02003   NaN  53.0  72.0  12.0
```

Or use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
g = df['months'].map({0:0, 3:1, 6:2, 9:3, 12:4})
df1 = df.groupby(['Subj', g])[['X','Y','Z']].sum().unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
```

Comment: thank you @jezrael your code works very well. I tried the groupby.cumcount but it seems it does not deal with missing data. For example, BAR02003 does not have data for "3months". So it should naturally leave the data cell blank. Instead, the "6month" data fills in for the "3months" data, "12month" data fills in for the "6month"data and so forth.

Comment: @WonChulChung - Can you test now?

Comment: Now all three methods are giving me the same error: "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". This is the kind of error i had when I naively applied df.pivot()

Comment: @WonChulChung - changed to `pivot_table` and added `aggfunc` parameter - here sum, can be mean or similar, can you test now?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) the duplicates, it will keep the first item:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [ { "Subj": "BAR02002", "months": 0, "X": 14, "Y": 53, "Z": 52 }, { "Subj": "BAR02002", "months": 3, "X": 24, "Y": 61, "Z": 96 }, { "Subj": "BAR02002", "months": 6, "X": 5, "Y": 53, "Z": 3 }, { "Subj": "BAR02002", "months": 9, "X": 3, "Y": 64, "Z": 33 }, { "Subj": "BAR02003", "months": 0, "X": 22, "Y": 63, "Z": 55 }, { "Subj": "BAR02003", "months": 6, "X": 44, "Y": 22, "Z": 53 }, { "Subj": "BAR02003", "months": 9, "X": 42, "Y": 12, "Z": 72 }, { "Subj": "BAR02003", "months": 12, "X": 15, "Y": 1, "Z": 12 } ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Result:

|  | Subj | months | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | BAR02002 | 0 | 14 | 53 | 52 |
| 4 | BAR02003 | 0 | 22 | 63 | 55 |